# Adding RequestMap

Tags: grails, spring-security

how can I upgrade an existing grails application with a request map? 
I didn't use

```
grails s2-quickstart package user role requestmap
```

but only

```
grails s2-quickstart package user role
```

AFAIK I have to 1) set a line in Config.groovy:

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.securityConfigType = "Requestmap"
```

and then 2) set all the entries via BootStrap.groovy (according to [spring's docs](http://grails-plugins.github.com/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/guide/5%20Configuring%20Request%20Mappings%20to%20Secure%20URLs.html#5.3%20Requestmap%20Instances%20Stored%20in%20the%20Database) ), I get that, but how does the RequestMap Domain Class have to look like? Anything else to do?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a simple class; this is what would be generated if you specify package `your.package.name` and class name `Requestmap`:

```
package your.package.name

class Requestmap {

   String url
   String configAttribute

   static mapping = {
      cache true
   }

   static constraints = {
      url blank: false, unique: true
      configAttribute blank: false
   }
}
```

Once you create this, add this line in `Config.groovy`:

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.requestMap.className = 'your.package.name.Requestmap'
```